# Select all records from one table and one column from other table and populate values in that one column based on some condition

Tags: java, mysql, querydsl

I have two tables `Pet` and `POST`.
In `POST`, I have a relationship between `Pet` and `User` table.
A user can mark a Pet as fav and an entry will add in `POST` table.

Now I want to retrieve all pets on landing page but also want to get a flag of the pets which are marked as favorite by the current user.
This is what I want to implement in QueryDSL.

Following code I have tried. But the code only return favorite pets of the user.   But my requirement is all the pets should be retrieved with a `fav_flag` as `true` for the pets which are marked as favorite.

I'm only getting the favorite pets for that user. But i want all pets to be displayed and a get a flag true for the favorite pets.

```
JPAQuery<PetListDTO> jpaQuery = jpaQueryFactory
    .select(Projections.fields(PetListDTO.class, qPet.id, qPet.petName, qPet.thumbnail.as("media"), qPet.price, qPet.owner.id.as("ownerId"), qPost.favorite.as("isFav"), qUserDetails.isCertified.as("isCertified")))
    .from(qPet)
    .leftJoin(qUserDetails).on(qUserDetails.user.id.eq(qPet.owner.id))
    .leftJoin(qPost).on(qPost.pet.id.eq(qPet.id)).where(qPost.buyer.id.eq(browsePetRequestDTO.getUserId()))
    .where(filterBrowsePetOption)
    .offset(pageable.getOffset())
    .limit(pageable.getPageSize());
List<PetListDTO> res = jpaQuery.fetch();
```

Input will be `browsePetRequestDTO.getUserId() = 4`.
Expected output is List of PetListDTO. e.g:

> [ { fav: true fromOtherSource: false id: 77 media: "s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-petquest-dev/images/…" ownerId: 7 petName: "Test New" petStatus: null price: 123 }, { fav: false fromOtherSource: false id: 77 media: "s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-petquest-dev/images/…" ownerId: 7 petName: "Test New" petStatus: null price: 123 } ]

Comment: @Tiw 
Currently by the above code,I'm only getting fav pets for the logged in user.
Input will be browsePetRequestDTO.getUserId() = 4. 
Expected output is List of PetListDTO e.g:
[
 {
   fav: true
fromOtherSource: false
id: 77
media: "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-petquest-dev/images/1547633429955.jpg"
ownerId: 7
petName: "Test New"
petStatus: null
price: 123
}, 
{
  fav: false
fromOtherSource: false
id: 77
media: "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-petquest-dev/images/1547633429955.jpg"
ownerId: 7
petName: "Test New"
petStatus: null
price: 123
 }
]

Comment: Got your idea, sorry cannot help you about this. Help you edited your question better. So where's your command failed at? - What's the output now?

Comment: The normal thing for sql questions is that you post sample data and expected output, maybe this could help or at least that you add the definition of the Post table. I see there is some expected result included but I can't understand it.

Comment: @Tiw Now I'm only getting the favorite pets for that user. But i want all pets to be displayed and a get a flag true for the favorite pets.

Comment: @AshishKumar  Add this description to your question would be better :)